# On exisitance a finite group

Tags: group-theory, gap

Do there exists group $G$ such that

$$\dfrac{G}{Z(G)}\cong\langle a,b,x\mid a^8=b^8=x^4=1,a^4=b^4=x^2, [a,x]=[b,x]=1, [a,b,b]=[a,b,a]=[b,a,a]=[b,a,b]=1\rangle.$$

Comment: Could you write a little about why you ask? What group is that, and why do you care if it can be the quotient by a center?

Comment: Yes, I know that the general question is of interest, but that does not intrinsically make any question of this form with some specified group interesting (there are just too many to pick out some specifically unless one has good reason for picking those).

Comment: Why negative Vote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not.

As the (gap) tag was given this is presumably intended as a request on how to do this calculation. First construct the group and convert it to a `PcGroup`:

```
f:=FreeGroup("a","b","x");
rels:=ParseRelators(f,"a8=b8=x4=1,a4=b4=x2,[a,x]=[b,x]=1,[[a,b],b]=[[a,b],a]=[[b,a],a]=[[b,a],b]=1");
g:=f/rels;
Size(g);
g:=Image(IsomorphismPcGroup(g));
```

The command `IsCentralFactor` tests whether a group is capable, in this case it returns `false`, thus the group is not capable.